# Abrir form maximizado na tela inteira

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um form principal, que contem todas as opções do sistema e gostaria de saber como abrir esse maximizado na tela inteira, se possível, se adaptando as diferentes resoluções.

IMAGEM DO FORM
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CÓDIGO

```
namespace Projeto_Funcionario
{
    public partial class Principal : Form
    {
         public Principal()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Acho que seria bom você mostrar um pouco do seu código. Este é o form principal do seu programa, ou uma janela secundária?

Comment: @Molx é o form principal do meu programa, vou postar um print e o código até o momento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode definir a propriedade `WindowState` para `FormWindowState.Maximized`.

- pelo código:

  ```
  namespace Projeto_Funcionario
  {
      public partial class Principal : Form
      {
           public Principal()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
               this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
           }
      }
  }
  ```
- pelo designer:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado!